# Comparing 2 columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I am trying to compare 2 columns for similarities.
There are strings in columns A and B and I want to display when a particular row of Col A matches the corresponding row in Col B. Note some of the rows in Col A might be empty.

So, basically this => `if (A1==B1), C1 = TRUE`

Here's what I've tried so far:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B1:B1,0)),"",A1)`

`=EXACT(A1,B1)`

`=IF(A1=B1,"True",B1)`

None of these give me a match for columns that contains the following data:

`ColA`                            `ColB`

`Xanthomonas oryzae`         `Xanthomonas oryzae`

Would appreciate help with this. Thanks!

Comment: This should work `=IF(A1=B1,"True",B1)`. So I suggest you test for extra spaces if you are not getting "true". Perhaps try `=TRIM(A1)=TRIM(B1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @Carl's answer does not work for you, the cell contents are *not* equal.  Check for  excess spaces or other non printing characters.

Try these

```
=CLEAN(A1)=CLEAN(B1)
```

or

```
=TRIM(A1)=TRIM(B1)
```

or

```
=TRIM(CLEAN(A1))=TRIM(CLEAN(B1))
```

`Trim` will remove leading and trailing spaces, `Clean` will remove ascii characters 0 through 31.  You may need a more elaborate formula depending on where the differences lie.

Answer (score -2):

In C1, place the formula

```
=A1=B1
```

Comment: If you had read the OP post in full before answering then you would have realised his/her data was the issue, not the test

Comment: @brettdj I did read the post in full and as best I can understand it, my solution is correct.  Perhaps it is poorly worded.

Comment: Your formula is a more concise version of `=IF(A1=B1,"True",B1)`. ie if `=IF(A1=B1,"True",B1)` fails then `=A1=B1` will fail as well. This is why I suggested `=TRIM(A1)=TRIM(B1)`