# Comparing 2 colums in excel

Tags: excel

I would like to compare 2 columns in excel. Both columns are the name of companies.The name of companies are not all time the same. An example is: in one list I have ABBEY and in other one Abbey National.It is the name of the same company. The idea is to see which companies are present in both list. I got already some results but the matching is not perfect because I missed a lot of company which are présent in both list. I don't want to do the job manually.

This is an overview of my list1 and it ranked from 1 to 533

```
ABBEY 
ABN AMRO
ACCOR
ACKERMANS
ACS
ACTELION
ADECCO
ADIDAS-SALOMON
AEGON
...
```

The second list is and it is ranked from 1 to 813

```
3i Group PLC
3M Co.
A2A SpA
AAREAL BANK
ABB
Abbey National
ABN-AMRO Hldg
Abu Dhabi National Energy Company
Accell Group 
Accenture PLC Cl A
Accor
Acea
Achmea
Achmea Hypotheekbank
Adecco
ADP
ADT CORP
Aegon
...
```

I hope to find some help here

Comment: I see there's `ABN AMRO` and `ABN-AMRO Hldg`. That'll be difficult to compare with conventional matching methods... Or is that okay and you'll be dealing with those exceptions later manually?

Comment: This is the problem. ABN AMRO and ABN-AMRO Hdlg are considered as the same company. If I can a solution to match them , this will be perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing 2 columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068696/comparing-2-columns-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first list goes from cell `A2` down, one could try:

```
=OFFSET(List2;MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(A2; " "; "*"); List2; 0)-1;0;1;1)
```

(Replace `List2` with second list range).

This will convert all spaces in each element of first list to `*` and add an `*` to end.

`MATCH` will find records on second list that match this expression.

Comment: I have my two list on the same folder. The name of my first list is Issuer and the second list is Company name. So in colum C2 I filled in like this =OFFSET(Company Name;MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(A2; " "; "*"); Company Name; 0)-1;0;1;1) , I got this answer #NAME?. something is going wrong

Comment: You must place `$G$2:$G$813` or whatever instead of `Company name`!

Comment: Issuer is the name of the colum A, Company name is the name of colum B. As I want my results in colum C, so I copied ans pasted in C2 this formula =OFFSET($B$2:$B$813;MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(A2; " "; "*"); $B$2:$B$813; 0)-1;0;1;1) It is worked partially. I missed always companies like ABN-AMRO. Why?

Comment: Can you explain me more the formula you have used? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `ABN*AMRO*` should match `ABN-AMRO Hldg`... Can't understand. Use [Evaluate formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-HP010066254.aspx) and [function reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx) to realize how its done.

Comment: I did the checking but somethig for sure is gone wrong. Can I upload my file in order to allow you to make more checking?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe something like this, though it could return some superfluous results if a company name is similar to an issuer name for another company:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","*")&"*",B:B,1,0)
```

[Use `;` instead of `,` as required]

Comment: Jerry your formula is not working. Can I upload my file in order to allow you to make some checking?

Comment: @Viwanou Sure. Um, how are you going to do that?

Comment: Impossible to upload it

Comment: @Viwanou GoogleSpreadsheets? Or a free file hosting site? Dropbox?